# Showing if $f' \in L^2([1,\infty),m)$, then $\frac{f(x)}{x} \in L^2([1,\infty),m)$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f:[1,\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ be such that $f(1)=0$, $f'$ exists, is bounded, and $f' \in L^2([1,\infty),m)$, then if $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$, we have $g \in L^2([1,\infty),m)$.

Furthermore, show this fails when we replace $L^2$ with $L^1$.

**Attempt**

For the first part, I was planning on using integration by parts then realized it gets too messy with the absolute values and all so I tried a change of variables, would I be correct in putting say $x=yt$ then $dx=dt$.

And I get stuck at this step.

For the second part, I found a function and I want to know if it works. I found $f$ to being

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}.$$

Clearly $f(1)=0$. And $f'=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$ and this has integral from $1$ to $\infty$ of $0$ while $f(x)/x=\ln x$ diverges. So our $g$ wouldnt be in $L^1([1,\infty),m)$. Shoot n evermind $f(x)/x=\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$..I just noticed that sorry so neither one of my parts for this problem are ok..wow I was so excited

Comment: You could try Poincares inequality

Comment: Hardy's inequality

Comment: im not sure I see how Hardys inequality might be useful here, maybe you meant Holders inequality? @fwd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardy’s inequality.

We have for each $R>1$, and $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{R}\frac{|f(x)|^2}{x^2}\,dx&=\left[-\frac{|f(x)|^2}{x}\right]_{1}^{R}-\int_1^R\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)2ff’\,dx\\
&=-\frac{|f(R)|^2}{R}+2\int_1^R\frac{1}{x}ff’\,dx\\
&\leq 0+\int_1^R\epsilon\frac{|f(x)|^2}{x^2}+\frac{|f’(x)|^2}{\epsilon}\,dx.
\end{align}
Here, we have used the trivial inequality $2|ab|\leq |a|^2+|b|^2$ with $a= \sqrt{\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $b=\frac{f’(x)}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$.
So, by subtracting the $\int_1^R\epsilon\frac{|f(x)|^2}{x^2}\,dx$ term from both sides, we can rearrange the inequality (once $\epsilon$ is small enough, say $0<\epsilon<1$) and then take the limit $R\to\infty$ to get
\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{|f(x)|^2}{x^2}\,dx&\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}\int_1^{\infty}|f’(x)|^2\,dx.
\end{align}
If you really wanted to, you could now optimize over $\epsilon$ as well to get a better constant.

---

So, the point is that when doing the integration by parts, the boundary term at $x=1$ vanishes by hypothesis, while the one at $\infty$ appears with the correct sign so that the inequality points in the right way at the end. So, the upshot is that the boundary terms don’t matter. The rest is the standard trick of absorbing part of the RHS into a good LHS.

Comment: Question, could you help me on the second part? Ive tried all sort of functions prob like 20-30 diff functions. Neither work :(

Comment: @anonymous smooth out a function which has a graph like $/^{————————}$, i.e a smooth function which starts off $0$, say $f|_{(-\infty,1]}=0$, then increases for a little bit, then stays constant, say $f|_{[2,\infty)}=1$. Then, $f’$ is compactly supported (between $[1,2]$) so it is obviously integrable, but $f(x)/x$ looks like $1/x$ at infinity so not integrable.

Answer (score 1):

This deals with the case $f'\in L_2(1,\infty)$ with $f(1)=0$.
An application of the generalized Minkowski inequality yields
\begin{align}
\Big(\int^\infty_1\Big|\frac{1}{x}\int^\infty_0 \mathbb{1}_{[1,x)}(t)\,f'(t)\,dt\Big|^2\,dx\Big)^{1/2}&= \Big(\int^\infty_1\Big|\frac{1}{x}\int^\infty_0 \mathbb{1}_{[1/x,1)}(t/x)\,f'(xt/x)\,dt\Big|^2\,dx\Big)^{1/2}\\\
&=\Big(\int^\infty_1\Big|\int^\infty_0 \mathbb{1}_{[1/x,1)}(u)\,f'(xu)\,du\Big|^2\,dx\Big)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^\infty_1|f'(xu)|^2\mathbb{1}_{[1/x,1)}(u)\,dx\Big)^{1/2}\,du\\
&\leq\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^\infty_0|f'(xu)|^2\mathbb{1}(xu>1)\mathbb{1}(u<1)\,dx\Big)^{1/2}\,du\\
&\stackrel{s=xu}{=}\int^1_0u^{-1/2}\Big(\int^\infty_1|f'(s)|^2\,ds\Big)^{1/2}\,du\\
&\leq2\|f'\|_{L_2([1,\infty)}
\end{align}

Comment: and as $f' \in L^2$ we are done, right? since $\vert \vert f' \vert \vert_2 < \infty$, we have $\vert \vert g \vert \vert_2 \in L^2$?

Comment: Also, should you be starting with $\int_1^\infty \frac{\vert f(x) \vert^2}{\vert x \vert^2}dx$ as apposed to $\bigg( \int_1^\infty \bigg\vert \frac{1}{x} \int_0^\infty \chi_{[1,x)}(t)f'(t) dt \bigg\vert^2 dx \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: @anonymous: Notice that  $\big|\frac{f(x)}{x}\Big|^2=\Big|\frac1x\int^\infty_0\mathbb{1}_{[1,x)}(t)f'(t)\,dt\Big|^2$.